# The plugin `flutter_webview_plugin` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding

Tags: flutter, dependencies, pubspec

I have upgraded the flutter version to the latest (2.5.2). when I upgrade, some dependencies also upgraded. but some of them are not compatible with null-safe. Now I upgraded all dependencies which are supported to null-safe versions.

Now occurred following error when I try to `pub get`

```
The plugin `flutter_webview_plugin` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since
a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
```

I also checked with `flutter_webview_plugin` on https://pub.dev/packages there are no newer versions than I used one (V 0.4.0) and this is `null-safety` supported.

[image]

following the code which I added in `pubspec.yaml`

```
flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.4.0
```

is there any solution to solve this issue without downgrading the flutter version?

Answer (score 4):

There is an issue opened on [github](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/issues/921) since September 2021. It will be best to use another package like the [webview package](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) since the issue hasn't been fixed for a long time now.